# Entity Relation between 2 table with field name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am coding a project in ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF6, SQL Server 2008.

This is my table structure.

`User2Org`:

- `UserName` (foreign key to `User2Org`)
- `OrgId`

`User`:

- `UserName` (KEY)
- `Password`

`Package`:

- `Id` (KEY)
- `PackageName`
- `Username` (foreign key to `User2Org`)

My problem is mapping data between 2 tables with column `UserName` in tables `Package` and `User2Org` above.

```
var user2Org = Package.User2Org;
```

When `username` in `Package` is `'abc'` and `username` in `user2Org` is `'Abc'`, the value of the variable `user2Org` will be null.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem. (ex: auto lower case when I am using `User.User2Org`)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't got your table structure... can you please explain your question properly

Comment: @marc_s: Iam using SQL server 2008

Comment: Are you SURE that your issue is with case sensitivity and not some other issue (for example Lazy loading not populating the related entities)?

Comment: Make sure the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) of the database columns is case-insensitive.

Comment: @ GertArnold, Andrew Counts maybe this case.

Comment: How can i use case-insensitive in Entity ?????? Hix.

Comment: @GertArnold: Because change DB will cause many problem for my project. Can we have optional auto lower case when query in Entity??????